# Why Notblank annotation displaying message?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working on spring mvc web application. In application, I put `@NotBlank` annotation for validation on `username` field in sign up form. I fill the `username` field and click on `Submit` button that time i get validation error message, but I fill `username` field so why `BindingResult` produce error behind `username` field and my `@Size` annotaion is not worked if insert less than 3 or greater than 12 character.

Here down is code:

Entity:

```
public class Registration {
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Username can not be empty !")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 12, message = "Username must be in 3 to 12 character") // Not working
    private String username;
    
    private String email;
    private Boolean agree;

    // constructor, getter, setter and toString()
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/form")
public String formPage(Model mdl)
{
    mdl.addAttribute("registration", new Registration());
    return "form";
}
    
@PostMapping("/register")
public String registerUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("registration") Registration registration, 
            BindingResult result)
{
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        System.out.println(result);
        return "form";
    }
        
    return "success";
}
```

form.html:

```
<form class="bg-white p-5" th:action="@{/register}" method="post" th:object="${registration}">
    <h1 class="text-center pt-2 pb-2">Signup Form</h1>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
        <input type="text" 
            class="form-control"
            th:value="${registration.username}"
            id="username" />
        <p th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('username')}" th:text="${error}">
                        
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" 
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            th:value="${registration.email}"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" 
            class="form-check-input" 
            id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Xml for validation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Snapshot of problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       th:value="${registration.username}" 
       id="username"/>
```

You are missing the `name` attribute.

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       th:value="${registration.username}" 
       id="username" 
       name="username"/>
```

This will fix it.

The form normally is bound to an object - `Registration` in your case, using the `name` attributes of `input` tags. The annotations are working, the problem is that you are receiving `null` username in `Registration` due to that missing attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your input needs to use the binding syntax `*{..}`. Replace:

```
<input type="text" 
            class="form-control"
            th:value="${registration.username}"
            id="username" />
```

with:

```
<input type="text" 
            class="form-control"
            th:value="*{username}"
            id="username" />
```

Comment: Thank for help but same validation error get